# Evaluate $\int \cos(x)\sin^2(x)e^{\sin(x)} \, \text{d} x$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $\int \cos(x)\sin^2(x)e^{\sin(x)} \, \text{d} x$. When I first see it, I think it's use integration by parts. Because there's $e^{\sin(x)}$. But when I use integration by parts, then I use $u=e^{\sin(x)}$, it's a bad idea. Next step I use $u$ sustitution $u= \sin^2(x)$ and since it's derivative and it cancels out. How to do it next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $u=\sin x$ gives $\int u^{2}e^{u}du$. Integrate by parts twice to finish.

Comment: I integrated and got it was 0. First time I chose $u=u^2$ and $dv=e^udu$ and second time $u=e^u$ and $dv=2udu$. This is correct? Thank you

Comment: $\int u^{2}e^{u}du=e^{u} u^{2}-\int 2ue^{u}du=e^{u} u^{2}-2ue^{u}+2\int e^{u}du=e^{u} u^{2}-2ue^{u}+2e^{u}$ excluding the constant of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u = \sin x$, $du = \cos x$. Then the integral becomes $\int u^2 e^u du$. This can be computed by integrating by parts (twice).

Comment: I integrated and got it was 0. First time I chose $u=u^2$ and $dv=e^udu$ and second time $u=e^u$ and $dv=2udu$. This is correct? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the substitution $\:u=\sin x$, $\:\mathrm d u=\cos x\,\mathrm dx$. You obtain the standard integral $\;\int u^2\mathrm e^u\,\mathrm du$.

Comment: I integrated and got it was 0. First time I chose $u=u^2$ and $dv=e^udu$ and second time $u=e^u$ and $dv=2udu$. This is correct? Thank you

Comment: f you integrate by parts, this is the way to go, but check your computations. The derivative of $0$ can't be $u^2\mathrm e^u$. Other method: it is standard that the antiderivative of $p(u)\mathrm e^u$, where $p(u)$ is a polynomial, is $q(u)\mathrm e^u$, where $q(u)$ is a polynomial of the same degree.